# Linq items in a list exist in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists

### List 1

```
var hashTags = new List<HashTag>();
hashTags.Add(new HashTag
{
    Name =  "#HashTag1",
    Index = 1
});
hashTags.Add(new HashTag
{
    Name = "#HashTag2",
    Index = 2
});
hashTags.Add(new HashTag
{
    Name = "#HashTag3",
    Index = 3
});
hashTags.Add(new HashTag
{
    Name = "#HashTag4",
    Index = 4
});
```

### List 2

```
var hashTags2 = new List<HashTag>();
hashTags2.Add(new HashTag
{
    Name =  "#HashTag1",
    Index = 1
});
hashTags2.Add(new HashTag
{
    Name = "#HashTag3",
    Index = 3
});
hashTags2.Add(new HashTag
{
    Name = "#HashTag4",
    Index = 4
});
```

How do I check if all the elements in hashTags2 exist in hashTags? The index can be ignored and only the name matching is crucial.   I can write a for loop to check element but I am looking for a LINQ solution.

Comment: You need to create a comparer and use LINQ `Except` method to check if all elements are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `linq` approach.

```
hashTags2.All(h=> hashTags.Any(h1 => h1.Name == h.Name))
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F0EK1t)

Answer (score 3):

As only equality of the names is to be taken into account, the problem can be solved by first mapping to the names and then checking containment as follows.

```
var hashTags2Names = hashTags2.Select( iItem => iItem.Name );
var hashTagsNames = hashTags.Select( iItem => iItem.Name );
var Result = hashTags2Names.Except( hashTagsNames ).Any();
```

Comment: With the modified answer, we can even simplify with `Except`. we don't need `All`

Comment: @HariPrasad Thanks for the suggestion, I changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

So you want a boolean linq expression that returns true if the name of every element in hashTags2 exists in hashTags?

For this you want the function [Enumerable.All](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/04/21/c.net-little-wonders-any-and-all.aspx), you want that every Hashtag in hashTags2 ...

```
bool result = hashTags2.All(hashTag => ...)
```

what do you want to check for every hashTag in hashTags2? That the name is a name in hashTags. So we need the names of hashTags:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = hashTags.Select(hashTag => hashTag.Name);
```

and to check if an item is in a sequence: Enumerable.Contains.

Put it all together:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = hashTags.Select(hashTag => hashTag.Name);
bool result = hashTags2.All(hashTag => names.Contains(hashTag.Name));
```

Of if you want one fairly unreadable expression:

```
bool result = hashTags2.All(hashTagX =>
    hashTags.Select(hashTagY => hashTagY.Name)
            .Contains(hashtagX)))
```

Because of delayed execution there is no difference between the first and the second method. The first one will be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

With Linq to objects you will need at least one `IEqualityComparar`, to
tell linq how to compare objects and to determine when they are equal.

A simple comparer would be the following that uses the Name property to determine equality of your `HashTag`.

```
public class NameEquality : IEqualityComparer<HashTag>
{
  public bool Equals(HashTag tag, HashTag tag2)
  {
    return tag.Name == tag2.Name;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(HashTag tag)
  {
    return tag.Name.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

With this Equality Comparer you can use the linq method `Except()`, to get all Elements from your list `hashTag` that are not part of `hashTag2`.

```
hashTags.Except(hashTags2, new NameEquality())
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the join operator, however it is just a matter of taste, I guess:

```
var hashMatched = hashTags.Join(hashTags2,_o => _o.Name, _i => _i.Name, (_o,_i) => _o);
```